# Ocaml and/or Haxe on Android?

Tags: android, ocaml, haxe

I have not found much helpful information through my Web-searching and email-asking. I would like to compile Haxe on an Android device using a fully-functional Ocaml Android port. Binaries are available for Linux, Windows, and Macintosh, but all are x86. I have heard that Ocaml can cross-compile to ARM or something, but Android support was dead. Is that true? What has changed since 2012? I have Terminal IDE installed, so in theory it is possible for me to run command-line apps on my device. This should be sufficient for Haxe, but as an Ocaml program I assume that such would necessitate Ocaml's Android native code generator working flawlessly. Please fill me in on this, as I cannot find conclusive information in other channels.

Comment: This is a question about development software, not actual programming. If you had read the question, you would understand that I am inquiring if certain software is available. There is another question, "How do I do development on my Android device?", which is perfectly relevant and quite similar to my question, except I am asking if specific software is available. I read your rules, and I know what I'm doing.

Comment: So what is your question then? a) how to cross-compile (development) b) what cross-compilers/apps exist (*Is there an app for X*) c) what is the status of availability of X? d) can I run an Y binary on Android? Please forgive me if I have problems to figure. I've read your question multiple times, though; it's not that I just saw two programming languages and decided "development, off-topic".

Comment: Thank you for understanding. My question is, "what is the status of availability of X?", with X being Ocaml on/for Android, and I welcome as much information on the subject as I can get, because my end goal is to use the Haxe compiler on an actual Android device.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/vouillon/ocaml-android ?

Comment: There is also https://github.com/whitequark/opam-android now.